# I need to mask url in reactjs to hide the id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router-dom, rect

I have the following problem, I need to hide or mask the id that appears in the URL with another name, for example: http://localhost:3000/client/1
if the user changes the "1" to a "2" he can access the data of the ID "2", I was thinking of hiding the ID or just showing any other word example: http://localhost:3000/client/ myID, that way the user will not know what to modify, I will leave the code that I currently have

```
const { tableNumber } = useParams();          
<Link as={"cambiarID"} to={`/client/${tableNumber}`}>
   <Button className="botonHome" positive icon onClick={goToCart}>
     <Icon name="home"  /> | Categorias
   </Button>
</Link>
```

tableNumber is the ID number -
any help is appreciated

Comment: Hiding the Id is unintuitive, and will not solve the problem. If you have content which can be served publicly but only to certain users then you need to implement a permissions/role based access system on your server side which authenticates and validates every request per user

Comment: I understand, but the system is not based on authentications, the id is accessed through a QR, said QR has the URL of the respective ID, but from the URL I can exchange between IDs, I was thinking that if the ID has another name, the user does not will know where to mopdify to access another ID

Comment: In that case you could potentially use a non-incremental id, such as a GUID. Note that this is just security by obscurity though.

Comment: you can encrypt the id and send it to the URL when accessing the id then decrypt it, that is the basic solution for your problem